# convert or change dates format

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, object

I am facing an issue in javascript dates, i want to change minutes

my react component

```js
//real time date
var currDate = new Date();
var dd = new Date().setMinutes(currDate.getMinutes() - 30); //reduce 30 minutes
var ddPLus = new Date().setMinutes(currDate.getMinutes() + 30); //add 30 minutes
var ddPLusHour = new Date().setMinutes(currDate.getMinutes() + 60); //add 30 minutes
var reductedTime = new Date(dd);
var addedTime = new Date(ddPLus);
var addedHour = new Date(ddPLusHour);


console.log({ // this.setState({

  current: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),

  slotTime: reductedTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  }),
  slotTime1: new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  }),
  slotTime2: addedTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  }),
  slotTime3: addedHour.toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  })
})
```

my output

```
04:00 PM

04:46 PM

05:16 PM

05:46 PM
```

Expected output

```
04:00 PM

04:30 PM

05:00 PM

05:30 PM
```

what should i do? anyone help me?

Comment: I made a snippet without react to show the plain JS issues

Comment: The current date is dynamic, it's difficult to understand what you want. Put an example with the current date/time, and the date/time expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is hard to understand.

You could consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)

Did you mean

```js
const aMinute = 60000;
var currDate = new Date()
currDate.setHours(16,0,0,0,0); // remove when tested
const reductedTime = new Date(currDate.getTime() - (30*aMinute)); // reduce 30 minutes
const addedTime    = new Date(currDate.getTime() + (30*aMinute)); // add 30 minutes
const addedHour    = new Date(currDate.getTime() + (60*aMinute)); // add 1 hour


console.log({ // this.setState({

  current: currDate.toLocaleTimeString(),

  slotTime: reductedTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  }),
  slotTime1: new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { // why this? Same as currDate
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  }),
  slotTime2: addedTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  }),
  slotTime3: addedHour.toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  })
})
```

Comment: i also show current date as well [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)

Comment: so does my modifications help?

Comment: yes please also show `current date` in if minutes are [0 to 29] and min [29 to 59] [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)

Comment: What do you mean by `show current date in if minutes are [0 to 29] and min [29 to 59]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use moment.js library for any kind of Dates format change and calculation. it has many builtin useful method.
e.g.

```
 const date = moment(new Date(), "hh:mm:ss A")
        .add(seconds, 'seconds')
        .add(minutes, 'minutes')
        .format('LTS');
```